How to debug Volt component in Laravel using VSCode?
I'm currently stuck in how to debug logic that is written inside a Volt component. I use VSCode as IDE and Xdebug to debug the program. Setting up a breakpoint in regular PHP file is easy (thanks for all the maintainer). But it's not available on PHP logic written in Volt component *.blade.php..
On regular Laravel class, setting breakpoint is easy:

On Volt component, breakpoint is not available:


There's a series on Visual Code with a lesson dedicated to debugging:
https://laracasts.com/series/visual-studio-code-for-php-developers/episodes/13
or check this post you may find something helpfull
Here
